# Can page size and margins be set when sending data from Excel to Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have code like the following:

```
Dim blnNewApp As Boolean
Dim wordApp As Object
Dim wordDoc As Object
Dim j As Long

Set wordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

If wordApp Is Nothing Then
    Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    blnNewApp = True
End If

Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add()

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strSHEET_NAME)
    For j = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        strLineOfText = .Cells(j, "A").Text
    wordApp.Selection.TypeText strLineOfText
        wordApp.Selection.TypeParagraph

    Next j
End With

wordApp.Visible = True
AppActivate wordApp.Caption
```

If I want to set the page size and margins in the Word doc that gets created how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page size and margins are properties of the `PageSetup` object. Note that this kind of information can often be discovered by recording a macro...

Since the code in the question uses late-binding, the numerical values for paper sizes will need to be used instead of the enumeration (`wdPaperLetter` for example) and the margin values will need to be passed in ***points***.

I've adapted the code in the question to demonstrate. Also, I've made additional optimizations:

- Work with the objects (espcially `Range` objects), rather than `Selection` (similar logic as avoiding `ActiveCell` and `Activate` in Excel - it's more accurate)
- Use the `Document` object that's declared and

```
    Dim blnNewApp As Boolean
    Dim wordApp As Object   'Word.Application
    Dim wordDoc As Object   'Word.Document
    Dim wordRange as Object 'Word.Range
    Dim j As Long

    Set wordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    If wordApp Is Nothing Then
        Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        blnNewApp = True
    End If

    Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add()
    Set wordRange = wordDoc.Content

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strSHEET_NAME)
        For j = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

            strLineOfText = .Cells(j, "A").Text
            wordRange.Text = strLineOfText & vbCr  'vbCr = a new paragraph
            With wordDoc.PageSetup
              .PaperSize = 2 'wdPaperLetter
              .BottomMargin = 452 'CentimetersToPoints(1.5)
              .TopMargin = 700 'CentimetersToPoints(2)
              .LeftMargin = 680 'CentimetersToPoints(2)
              .RightMargin = 680 'CentimetersToPoints(2)
            End With
        Next j
    End With

    wordApp.Visible = True
    AppActivate wordApp.Caption
```

Comment: I get a function or sub not defined when I try any variant of this and no matter where I place the .PageSetup portion.  My main sub name is highlighted in yellow and the first InchesToPoints (I'm in the US so not using metric) line is highlighted.  I'm not worrying about .PaperSize at this point so I left that line out.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I forgot the code in the question uses late-binding, which means InchesToPoints (or CentimetersToPoints) won't be available. In that case, you need to pass the information *in points* @frankbean

Comment: @frankbean I've edited the answer and also added information about the paper size

Comment: ok that worked except I moved the With wordDoc.PageSetup part up below Set wordDoc = .  Where you have is inside a for loop that processes every row in a very large spreadsheet.  I didn't even try it there because it didn't make sense to have the setup process after every row is output.  Thanks!